# Jumping Ball in Unity without Character Controller

Tags: unity-game-engine, character, gravity

I would like to know how to make a ball jump in Unity without using a character controller. The ball needs to have a rigidbody for the gravity and a script to make it jump in the relative orientation of the ball. Can somebody help please.

Answer (score 0):

As skovacs1 [states on Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/27793/better-jumping-with-lerpz-character-controller.html):

> The simple answer is to tune the value of inAirControlAcceleration and
>   it should give you something more like what you imagine. For even more
>   control, you could also replace the compound assignment of
>   `movement.inAirVelocity` with
>
> ```c#
> movement.inAirVelocity +=
>     movement.direction * Time.deltaTime *
>     movement.inAirControlAcceleration
> ```
>
> so that the value is scaled by the
>   amount of input of h.
>
> If that still doesn't get you what you want, assuming that you are
>   using the exact script linked (because you didn't post anything else),
>   here's what the relevant functional code in Update here does:
>
> ```c#
> //move horizontally as calculated in UpdateSmoothedMovementDirection * speed
> //+ vertically by the speed calculated in ApplyGravity or ApplyJumping
> //+ horizontally + vertically by the inAirMovement calculated in ApplyJumping
> //+ horizontally by the adjustment to inAirMovement calculated in
> //UpdateSmoothedMovementDirection 
> var currentMovementOffset = movement.direction * movement.speed
>                             + Vector3(0,movement.verticalSpeed,0)
>                             + movement.inAirVelocity;
> currentMovementOffset *= Time.deltaTime;
> movement.collisionFlags = controller.Move (currentMovementOffset);
> ```
>
> All you seem to care about is the horizontal movement, so the only
>   variables you actually need to care about are movement.direction,
>   movement.speed and movement.inAirVelocity.
>
> The part that does the work:
>
> ```c#
> function UpdateSmoothedMovementDirection() { //called by Update every frame
>     //...irrelevant stuff
>     //move direction is *always* (canControl is never changed in this script)
>     //the horizontal input when the absolute horizontal input is greater than 0.1
>     if (movement.isMoving) movement.direction = Vector3 (h, 0, 0);
>
>     //calculate the speed change only when on the ground
>     if (controller.isGrounded) {
>         var curSmooth = movement.speedSmoothing * Time.deltaTime;
>         var targetSpeed = Mathf.Min (Mathf.Abs(h), 1.0);
>         if(Input.GetButton("Fire2") && canControl)
>             targetSpeed *= movement.runSpeed;
>         else
>             targetSpeed *= movement.walkSpeed;
>
>         movement.speed = Mathf.Lerp (movement.speed, targetSpeed, curSmooth);
>         //...irrelevant stuff
>     }
>     //inAirVelocity is going to be adjusted horizontally by Time.deltaTime
>     //in the direction of horizontal input
>     else {
>         //...irrelevant stuff
>         if (movement.isMoving)
>             movement.inAirVelocity += Vector3(Mathf.Sign(h),0,0) * Time.deltaTime
>                                       * movement.inAirControlAcceleration;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The part that sets initial inAirVelocity:
>
> ```c#
> function ApplyJumping() { //called by Update every frame
>     //...irrelevant stuff
>     //When on the ground and we can jump, the inAirVelocity will be 
>     //the motion of the platform we're on
>     if (controller.isGrounded) {
>         if (jump.enabled && Time.time < jump.lastButtonTime + jump.timeout) {
>             //...irrelevant stuff
>             movement.inAirVelocity = lastPlatformVelocity;
>             //...irrelevant stuff
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> What's probably not what you expect is that you only ever calculate
>   the speed when on the ground.
>
> Once in the air, you move at the speed
>   you were moving when you were last on the ground in the input
>   direction (`movement.direction`) + some adjustment affected by the input
>   direction (`inAirVelocity`).
>
> I assume this is supposed to simulate
>   inertia somehow, but it really doesn't work that way because you can
>   change direction still and there's no deceleration.
>
> To get proper direction on the inertia, you would need to move the
>   change to movement.direction into the `if(Controller.isGrounded)` block
>   which follows. To get the actual inertial deceleration, you would
>   subtract from speed in the else statement at some smoothing rate until
>   it is 0 and keep the `lastPlatformVelocity` separate from `inAirVelocity`,
>   add that as a separate term and decelerate it as well.
>
> To give full speed control while in the air, I recommend you move the
>   speed stuff out of that if block (in which case, `inAirVelocity` may not
>   need to be changed in `UpdateSmoothedMovementDirection`).
>
> Alternatively,
>   you can change what you use to calculate movement when jumping by
>   doing something like
>
> ```c#
> if(!controller.isGrounded) movement.speed = inAirSpeed;
> ```
>
> but this will result in some unnatural behaviour and you
>   will likely need to do some tuning in the air.